# Is it possible to use callback function in conjuction with sqlite_prepare_v2()

Tags: c, sqlite, callback

So I am having some problems with parameterized queries and combining them with callback functions in C.

So with sqlite3_exec(...) you can execute your SQL query and give a callback function as parameter with it. The callback function serves to print out the query output

But I want to use parameterized queries so I have to use  sqlite3_prepare_v2(), one of the sqlite3_bind functions, sqlite3_step(), and sqlite3_finalize(), which don't support callback functions as parameter.

Is there another function that I can use to get best of both worlds?
(side note: the SQL statement that I try to execute is just a single line query)

Comment: Short answer to the question as initially posed: no.

Comment: What is the nature of the problems you are having with combining the standard prepared-statement API with callback functions?  And what advantage do you seek to gain if, as I'm interpreting you to have said, there's only one SQL statement you want to execute anyway?  *Those* are things we might be able to help you with.

Comment: The problems are: 1) The function that I am writing kind of requires me to use callback functions to print the output(s). -> Problem 1: if i use parameterized queries this wont suffice. 2) If i use parameterized queries, I'm not quite sure how to print out the SQL query output (all columns).

Comment: Use `sqlite3_column_XXX()` functions to access the returned values as you step through the result rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the lead remark from [the API docs for `sqlite3_exec()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html):

> The sqlite3_exec() interface is a convenience wrapper around
>   sqlite3_prepare_v2(), sqlite3_step(), and sqlite3_finalize(), that
>   allows an application to run multiple statements of SQL without having
>   to use a lot of C code.

Things you should take away from that include:

- the callback-based interface is not the main API.
- it's written in terms of other accessible functions, so you could write your own, similar function that provides whatever callback interface you want.

If you really do need a callback interface that works with parameterized prepared statements, then you will indeed need to write an appropriate analogue of `sqlite3_exec()` yourself.  If you want to stick as close as possible to `sqlite3_exec()` then you could use a similar signature, with a pointer to the (already prepared and filled) prepared statement in place of the first two parameters.  The function would then need to execute the query via multiple calls to `sqlite3_step()`, each time extracting the needed data from the result row (`sqlite3_column_sometype()` * n), passing them to the callback function, and handling the callback's return value appropriately.

There's a lot of room for customization there, especially if you indeed have only one query to support.  You might, for example, pass the parameters to the function instead of requiring them to be pre-bound.  You might very well change the signature of the callback function to be better matched to the query results, and if there's only one query to be supported then it probably doesn't need to be told the column names.

If it turns out that you actually know the specific function that is supposed to be called per row, then it doesn't have to be a *callback* interface at all, in that you you receive a function pointer as a parameter.  In that case, you could just call the function directly.